# Editing Old Commit in git

Tags: git

I want to redesign my Graphical User Interface in Visual Studio C#.I am using git bash for this purposes since I have a commit log of all my work.
I entered the following command

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Then my notepad++ edit popped up since I configured that.Now I type edit before the commit message where I would do my redesigning of form after that git showed me two commands

```
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

I entered `git commit --amend` and it again opened up my notepad++ form then I opened my visual studio form and redesigned the form after that I closd both my visual studio and notepad++ and typed  `git rebase --continue` but it did not worked.

So my question is that in what point of time I should make changing in my Visual Studio Form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the rebasing pauses, you should do your changes. Then you add those changes like you usually do for a commit (using `git add`). But instead of committing them as a new commit, you amend the previous one using `git commit --amend`. This will change the commit you are currently editing.

After that, use `git rebase --continue` to continue rebasing and applying the later commits.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed poke It was taking devil out me.

Comment: Another problem I am facing is that In my sample project TestForm in visual studio which I am tracking from git bash,whenever I open or close my visual studio project using cancel button git status shows me the untracked file TestForm.suo why is that? and how to avoid it?

Comment: `.suo` is a user-specific configuration file that is created by VisualStudio to keep track of some unimportant settings (like opened folders and stuff). You should add it to your `.gitignore`, so it doesn’t get recognized by Git.

Comment: I checked in .gitignore it was already there then why it still keeps popping in git status?

Answer (score 1):

you should do your changes BEFORE the

```
git commit --amend
```

because "amend" means: take the changed and "amend" them to the last commit. Since you are in the process of rebasing; these changes will thus be applied on the commit where you are at that moment.

***in summary:***

1. git rebase -i HEAD~3 (and choose "edit" to edit the commit you want)
2. Do your changes in visual studio or wherever you want
3. git commit --amend
4. git rebase --continue