# How to edit (correct) a file from an old commit, and make that change in all commits after it?

Tags: git

I have this linear series of commits:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F, G
                  ^
                 HEAD
```

A couple of files in commit D have errors, which need to be fixed in commit D and all following commits (E, F, and G). This is a private repository, so I can just overwrite everything.

Almost all of my Git experience is

```
git add --all :/
git commit -m 'Commit msg'
git push -u origin branchname
```

This question

- *[Editing Old Commit in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079335/editing-old-commit-in-git)*

discusses rebasing, but that seems to be related to merging two branches. I'm hesitant to experiment, for fear of permanently damaging the repository. Perhaps that implies I should be branching and then merging...

What is the proper way of going about this?

Comment: Rebasing can be used for this, too; just try what’s given in the question you linked to (but stage your changes with `git add` before `git commit --amend`, as stated in the answer).

Comment: possible duplicate of [editing commits with git rebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211767/editing-commits-with-git-rebase)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your current branch is `master`,

```
git checkout $D
# fixup file here
git commit -a --amend  # fixup in added commit (w/o --amend) is also a good option
git rebase @ master  # <-- or git rebase HEAD master, same thing
```

Be aware that all the rebased or amended commits in `$D^..master` will be rewritten, but no other children of `$D^` -- if you have branch points downstream of `$D` you'll have to rebase those onto the new history separately.

This is pretty much identical to the `rebase --interactive` suggestions in linked answers/questions, but when only one thing needs fixing up I find it more pleasingly direct to just do it myself.

Comment: what does the `$` signify in your answer?

Comment: It's shell parameter-expansion syntax, I meant it here as "however you want to refer to commit D".

Comment: Both the marked-as-duplicate question and the one I linked to in the question-post use `git rebase --continue`. Can you explain the difference between that and `git rebase @ master`? Thank you, @jthill.